# web.config ignoring httpmodules section

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config

I am trying to add a custom httpmodule to the httpModules section of a web.config in a rather large .NET app.

The module did not seem to actually be getting hit after I added it.

On a whim, I changed one of the default modules to be wrong to see what happens:

This:

```
<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Became this:

```
<add name="ScriptModule" type="Blah.Blah.Blah, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

The app still works!  It compiles and runs fine...somehow.  If I create a new web app from scratch and make the same change it breaks as expected.

How is this possible?  I am absolutely positive that it is the right web.config. If I purposely break other parts of it(or change the  tag to  even) the app throws an error like it should.

Comment: iis7?`/*i hate stupid minimum*/`

Comment: D'oh.   Integrated Pipeline strikes again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2010/09/16/HttpModule-Not-Working-In-IIS7.aspx